# Two display backlight devices (powertop) draining battery life in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, power-management, battery, backlight

I hardly getting 1hour battery life on my hp laptop,I found that two instances with same name  (from PowerTop v2.9 statistics) draining huge amount of battery. please any solution.

here is the screenshot[image]

Comment: 4W is not a huge amount, and the total 11.4W are reasonable for an idle laptop as well. Depending on your battery's capacity it should last for 3-4 hours. How old is your laptop's battery? Most likely it's just the battery being worn out.

Comment: Of course 4w not a huge amount @Sebastian, but it affecting directly with my battery life than any other application. and my battery was fine. Thank you.

Comment: You _assume_ that this is what's affecting your battery life. My laptop has the same power consumption on battery, and it lasts for 3-4 hours when idle. Have you made sure that powertop did the required minimum number of measurements as explained in the user guide? What is your battery's nominal capacity (see Power Manager settings)?